# How to generate json string if the `Json.obj` contains a `None` value?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, implicit, scala-option

In playframework:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val obj = Json.obj(
  "aaa" -> 111,
  "bbb" -> Some(222)
)

println(obj.toString)
```

Which outputs:

```
{"aaa":111,"bbb":222}
```

But if I change the code to:

```
val obj = Json.obj(
  "aaa" -> 111,
  "bbb" -> None
)
```

It can't be compiled, and reports:

```
Error:(6, 17) diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Writes[None.type]
starting with method OptionWrites in trait DefaultWrites
  "bbb" -> None
           ^
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Do you mean `play.api.libs.json.JsNull` ?

Comment: It should be `None`, the value is actually from a field of other objects, which is an `Option`

Comment: If it is `None`. The corresponding json should not contains this field, rather than return a javascript `null` value.

Comment: But it can't be compiled

Comment: How about define a Writes[XXX]？ Using [macro](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception)

Answer (score 0):

`Json.obj` works fine with `None` if it is a field of an object as you say:

```
case class A(aaa: Int, bbb: Option[Int])
defined class A

val a = A(1, None)
a: A = A(1,None)

Json.obj("aaa" -> a.aaa, "bbb" -> a.bbb)
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"aaa":1,"bbb":null}
```

You can make your example work as well if your `None` is an `Option`, not just `None.type` as compiler says:

```
Json.obj("aaa" -> 111, "bbb" -> None.asInstanceOf[Option[Int]])
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"aaa":111,"bbb":null}

Json.obj("aaa" -> 111, "bbb" -> Option[String](null))
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"aaa":111,"bbb":null}
```